# Adjusting the attribute `hue` with a condition using the lmplot from seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Hello I am using an lmplot to compare three features `price`, `make` and `year`. I want to use `make` as the feature of interest and apply it to the attribute hue. The plot works. However, what if I want to add a condition to neaten the visualization and improve accuracy. I wish to get the top 20 makes instead of using all as seen in the visualization below
. Is that possible? Help would be appreciated for this. I have also provided the code below that. 
[image]

```
"""  An lmplot is used to analyze multiple variables together there. The three variables that will be looked at here are: 
- Make 
- Price
- Year 
"""

# Setting up the plot
g = sb.lmplot(x="year", y="price", hue="make",
               truncate=True, size=10, data=carmax_data)

plt.title(' Comparing Car Make prices over the years')
```

Comment: Top 20 makes by what measure?

Comment: You would need to supply a dataframe with "the top 20 makes" (whatever that means) to the `data` argument.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. Instead of using all I only want the twenty, But I am not sure how or what method to use @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Please note that we have no idea what the dataframe contains and what "the top 20" means.

Comment: ok another thing is there anyway to use jitter or anything to reduce the shape size of the dots then? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest